# pycharm generates wrong target path for tests

Tags: python, pycharm

using Pycharm 2017.1.3 (but saw it in other versions as well) - 
When running single test (right click the test and run), the test target configuration that automatically created is wrong - before the class name it puts dot (.) instead of colon(:), so it looks like it's a function. For that reason, when running the single test, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/...../python3.6/site- 
packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
File "/Users/...../python3.6/site- 
packages/nose/loader.py", line 523, in makeTest
return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
File "/Users/...../python3.6/site- 
packages/nose/loader.py", line 576, in _makeTest
if issubclass(parent, unittest.TestCase):
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

for example, this target:

```
myproject.utils.tests.test_integration.MyNewService.test_use_case
```

should be:

```
myproject.utils.tests.test_integration:MyNewService.test_use_case
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening regardless to PyCharm, NoseTest is looking for `:` delimiter between filename and class

If you run with different test suit, it will run

In general, PyCharm is running a test helper for running tests

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pycharm/django_test_manage.py

If you override its default values (changing `TEST_RUNNER` value for instance), you might experience problems

Comment: Hi @gcoh did you find the solution on how to do this?

Comment: yes, go to Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Django | Settings and set the settings.py file

Comment: I have already done this correctly to correct settings.py file, if I didnt do this even Pycharm > Django server Run will not work I believe, and Run is working fine, so i am sure I have done setup of settings.py in Django > Settings in Pycharm preference correctly, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, the problem appears to be a custom `settings.py` file name.

PyCharm won't automatically discover it, so it needs to be configured manually in

**Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Django | Settings**